# Loading a local file via a external webpage inside WebView

Tags: html, android-webview

I am loading a website inside a WebView, for example: `www.example.com`

The code for `example.com` is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example | Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="window.location.href = 'file:///android_asset/index1.html';">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, like you can see there is a `href` for local android file `file:///android_asset/index1.html`,

That is what I am willing to accomplish, Loading a local file through a external website inside WebView Please guide me on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to Cordova & Dropped the idea of interlinking the pages, rather I programmed the pages using REST API via Wordpress.